# Use to dictionary to relace certain specific values

Tags: r

I have the following ilst

```
list <- c("AB", "G", "H")
```

Now I have certain letters that should be replaced. So fe. B and H should be replaced.

So what I have not is:

```
replace_letter <- c("B", "H")

for(letter in replace_letter){
 for (i in list){
  print(i)
  print(letter)
  if(grepl(letter, i)){
   new_value <- gsub(letter,"XXX",i)
   print("yes")
   }
   else{
   print("no")
   }
  }
}
```

However the XXX in my code should be replace by certain lookup values/.
So instead a B -> B+, in stead of H -> H**.

So I need some kind of dictionary function to replace the XXX with something specific.

Does anybody have suggestion how I can include this in the code above?

Comment: What is the expected replaced output?

Comment: That depends on how your replacement should look like. If you want to exchange A-> B, B->C you can do that simple with two lines. If you want whole words, you need a dataset from somewhere and adjust it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data and dictionary**

```
dictionary <- data.frame(From = LETTERS,
                         To = LETTERS[c(2:length(LETTERS), 1)], stringsAsFactors = F)
set.seed(1234)
data <- LETTERS[sample(length(LETTERS), 10, replace = T)]
```

Here is the **replace-function**

```
replace <- function(input, dictionary){
   dictionary[which(input == dictionary$From),]$To
}
```

**Apply it** to data:

```
sapply(data, replace, dictionary = dictionary)

# C   Q   P   Q   W   Q   A   G   R   N 
# "D" "R" "Q" "R" "X" "R" "B" "H" "S" "O"
```

You just have to adjust your dictionary according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I use the function `plyr::mapvalues` to do this. The function takes three arguments, the strings to do the replacement on, and two vectors `from` and `to` that define the replacement.

e.g.

```
plyr::mapvalues(letters[1:3], c("b", "c"), c("x", "y"))
# [1] "a" "x" "y"
```

Answer (score 0):

I switched to the newer `dplyr` library, so I'll add another answer here:

In an interactive session I would enter the replacements in `dplyr::recode` directly:

```
dplyr::recode(letters[1:3], "b"="x", "c"="y")
# [1] "a" "x" "y"
```

Using a pre-defined dictionary, you'll have to use `UQS` to unquote the dictionary due to the tidy-eval semantics of `dpylr`:

```
dict <- c("b"="x", "c"="y")
dict
# b   c 
# "x" "y" 
dplyr::recode(letters[1:3], UQS(dict))
# [1] "a" "x" "y"
```